# Where is the meaning of system constants such as _SIG_MAXSIG defined?

Tags: operating-system, posix, freebsd

In FreeBSD we have the constant `_SIG_MAXSIG` defined in [_sigset.h](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sys/_sigset.h?v=FREEBSD9;im=3#L45). I am wondering where the meaning of this constant is defined. Obviously, this is something like the maximal signal value. However, I am looking for a definite standard, the common ground that all developers should look at when interpreting that value. The same holds true for the meaning of other constants -- what is the definite source defining their meaning?

Comment: Hint: identifiers starting with `_` are *usually* private and not standardized.

Comment: Thanks @larsmans, that helps. Is there a standard saying that identifiers starting with `_` are....? ;-).

Comment: C99, section 7.1.3 says "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use", but that's about as close as you're going to get. :-)

Comment: ... however, POSIX and C99 between them do standardize `_exit` and `_Exit`, and maybe a few more `_.*` idents that I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't answer your question directly, because I'm unaware of a standard that specifies `_SIG_MAXSIG` (I don't think it is standardized), but much of what you're looking for is defined by the [Single Unix Specification](http://www.unix.org/version4).  Note: you have to register with the site in order to download the specification.

Section XSH 2.4 explains the signal-related concepts.  I don't see anything about the maximum number of signals though, other than `SIGRTMIN` and `SIGRTMAX`--which are for real-time signals.

Comment: You can browse the POSIX standard online at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ though; this is the basis for the SUS. (Not sure what the SUS adds to it.)

Comment: @larsmans Thank you!  I thought there was a link to it, but I've had them locally for some time now so I figured something changed about the site.  Thanks again.

Comment: Your answer helps, thanks! I already googled for `sites:pubs.opengroup.org _SIG_MAXSIG` and did not get a result, so I had the suspicion that this constant is not part of SUS or POSIX. Considering that it is not *standardized*, is it explained somewhere? I would be surprised if the meaning of this constant is nowhere explained within the FreeBSD or any other BSD project at least...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe there is.  Many projects suffer from a lack of documentation.  It's hard to keep up with all the changes, and it's quite an effort to even start.  If you're interested in the BSD source, it might be best to checkout [The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Implementation-FreeBSD-Operating-System/dp/0321968972/).  I read it's predecessor, *The Design and Implementation of the 4.4 BSD Operating System*, and it was very good.

Comment: You should be able to grep through the kernel and libc sources to find out where the identifier is used. BSD code is usually quite readable (unlike, say, GNU code) to someone with a good grasp of basic Unix concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, this is as much as I can get I believe.